# Is there a way to make a custom library in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

So I have a set of functions that I call in almost every script I write. Is there a way to store them that I can call them without pasting 100 lines of code in every project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For in depth details, have a look at [**Creating a Library**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW6) in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1).

As a quick *example*, in **macOS Catalina**, I created the **Script Libraries** *folder* in the **Library** *folder* of my **Home** *folder*, in **Terminal**:

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/Library/Script Libraries"
```

In **Script Editor**, I saved a *script* named **My Library.scpt** in the **Script Libraries** *folders* in the **Library** *folder* of my **Home** *folder*, containing a *handler* I use often with **Safari**:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
to waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    --  # Wait for page to finish loading in Safari.
    --  # This works in **macOS Catalina** and 
    --  # macOS Big Sur and may need adjusting for
    --  # other versions of macOS.
    tell application "System Events" to repeat until ¬
        exists (buttons of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading
```

I then used the `waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()` *handler* in another *script* in this manner:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property myLibrary : script "My Library"

property theURL : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581982/" & ¬
    "is-there-a-way-to-make-a-custom-library-in-applescript"

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

myLibrary's waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()

display alert "The web page has finished loading!"
```

In the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown directly above, **Safari** waits for the *web page* to finish loading, using a *handler* from **My Library.scpt**, and then displays an *alert message*.

---

> **Note:** Libraries are supported in OS X Mavericks v10.9 (AppleScript 2.3) and later. To share properties and handlers between scripts in prior OS versions, use the [load script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW35) command as described in [Libraries using Load Script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_load_script.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH227-SW1).

Note that the `load script` *method* can still be used with newer versions of the **OS**.

**Update:**

Also note that the question asked was about "Is there a way to make a custom library in AppleScript?", **not** how to use them and why I said "As a quick *example*". However, that said, for practical long term usage, to the point mentioned in the other answer, I'd use e.g.:

```
set myLibrary to ¬
    load script alias ¬
        ((path to library folder from user domain as text) & ¬
            "Script Libraries:My Library.scpt")
```

Instead of:

```
property myLibrary : script "My Library"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the method as described in the accepted answer to this post, is the same method I used when I first started creating and using **Script Libraries**.

I eventually realized, and learned the hard way, **there is a big pitfall with this method**.

For example, let’s say that you have created 20 different script files that call on Handlers from your Script Library “My Library.scpt” file.  Then one day you decide to edit your Script Library “My Library.scpt” file then re-save the file.  You then come to realize that the 20 different script files that use the  “My Library.scpt” file are not using the new re-saved edited version of your Library file.  They are still running the code from the previous version. This is because the scripts that use those libraries load its code at compile time.  In other words, for those 20 script files you created to be able to use the updated code in the “My Library.scpt” file,  you now need to painstakingly comb through all of your script files, trying to remember which files called on your “My Library.scpt” file and open, re-compile, and save each one again.  Trust me… it’s a nightmare!

The work around for his problem is to have your script files load the Script Library file every time it runs.  This ensures that he scripts which are using the “My Library.scpt” library file are using it’s latest version.

To do this, you would have to change the code in the Accepted Answer from this…

```
property myLibrary : script "My Library"

property theURL : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581982/" & ¬
    "is-there-a-way-to-make-a-custom-library-in-applescript"

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

tell myLibrary to waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()

display alert "The web page has finished loading!"
```

to this…

```
set myLibrary to load script alias ((path to home folder as text) & ¬
    "Library:Script Libraries:My Library.scpt")

property theURL : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581982/" & ¬
    "is-there-a-way-to-make-a-custom-library-in-applescript"

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    make new document with properties {URL:theURL}

tell myLibrary to waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()

activate
display alert "The web page has finished loading!"
```

Comment: Properties has always been set at compile time, which can bite you if you are not careful.  The solution for a library is the `use` statement, as in `use myLibrary : script "My Library"`, which imports the terms at run time.

Comment: @user3439894 With your “My Library.scpt” already saved and the script file that calls the `waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()` has already been compiled and successfully run, go back to your “My Library.scpt”  and add a `beep 5` command after `end repeat` and re save your “My Library.scpt” . Without re-compiling the the script that calls the `waitForSafari…` Handler, run it again  and you will see `beep 5` doesn’t run. The script that calls the `waitForSafari…`  handler has to be recompiled then run to be able to run the updated `beep 5` code in the “My Library” script

Comment: @red_menace what I just explained above, still holds true even while using the `use myLibrary : script "My Library"`

Comment: I just tested with an application, which sees changes in the library.  The library is loaded at run time so that one included in an application can override one in the user's library, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I stated that I have functions that I always use. That implies that those functions never change. I hope it's OK for you if I don't set your answer as the accepted answer since user3439894's answer came first.